# Symbolic equation with matrix terms

Tags: matrix, symbolic, calculus-and-analysis

I'm searching for a way to develop or much more optimize a symbolic equation in the form:

$\qquad f = ((I_{nxn}+\lfloor A_{nxn} \rfloor)*B_{nxn})*((I_{nxn}+\lfloor C_{nxn}\rfloor)*D_{nxn})*V_3$

This contains n x n matrices, skew matrix $\lfloor foo \rfloor$, identity matrix $I$ and a vector. Mathematica would need to respect the order of multiplication.

The final goal is to get the derivative for some of these variables.

I saw the solving and derivative function but the solving function does not seem to respect the order of multiplication since it doesn't know that the symbols are matrices.

Comment: In Mathematica, `*` always means ***scalar*** multiplication. Perhaps you should be looking at `,` (`Dot`).

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you are trying to achieve? How large is n?

Comment: Hello @mikado n will be 3 in this case. The matrices are rotation matrices.

Comment: @m_goldberg I just tried it and it works, thank you. Now I just need to figure out to tell Mathematica that $I$ is an Identity matrix, $V$ is a vector and to respect the property that the skew-symmetric matrix only works with vectors. Am I maybe missing something, is this the way a symbolic expression would be defined or is this too specific?

Comment: `IdentityMatrix[n]` is the n x n identity matrix.